# Como puedo Juntar el Label y el Input en un formulario

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy realizando un formulario, pero a la hora de ya verlo visualmente, me quedan muy separados la descripción(label) del input
La verdad no se mucho de diseñar paginas web, solo agarro una plantilla y la voy modificando sobre ese, utilizo bootstrap
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi lo tengo en el diseño

```html
<!--BLOQUE 1-->
            
            <div class="row form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-1 control-label ">Nombre:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Nombre(s)" onkeyup="Mayusculas(this)" class="form-control" id="Nombre" autocomplete="off">
                </div>

                <div class="mb-md hidden-lg hidden-xl"></div>
                <label class="col-lg-1 ">Apellido Paterno:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Apellido Paterno" onkeyup="Mayusculas(this)" class="form-control" id="Apelllido_Paterno" autocomplete="off">
                </div>

                <div class="mb-md hidden-lg hidden-xl"></div>
                <label class="col-lg-1 ">Apellido Materno:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Apellido Materno" onkeyup="Mayusculas(this)" class="form-control" id="Apelllido_Materno" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Hola

Creo que solo debes reducir el tamaño de la clase col o inclusive borrarla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias intentar cambiando en la clase de la columna cambiar un lg(large) por un sm (small)

```
 <div class="row form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label ">Nombre:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Nombre(s)" onkeyup="Mayusculas(this)" class="form-control" id="Nombre" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
```

Y si esto no reduce el espacio, la otra opcion es eliminar las clases o colocarlas como en este ejemplo:

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Que lo que haría seria poner los label´s encima de los input's, es cuestion de "jugar" un poco con las clases.  Otra soluccion seria agregar CSS.